# Exact p-values for real world outcomes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I had an interesting exam question yesterday, in which you had the outcomes of number people killed in traffic accidents in two subsequent years (the second being relatively higher than the first). Now you should calculate the **exact p-value** for the hypothesis that the second outcome was due to a chance event.

The idea was that you should assume that the number of fatalities in traffic accidents was Poisson distributed then you should test for the parameter-ratio being 1. But is this really an "exact p-value" for this hypothesis. Since the Poisson distribution is just an approximation this is neither an exact p-value in theory nor in practice.

How do you more experienced statisticians look at this?

Comment: I think you misinterpret what exact means. Calculate the exact p-value for a given a model means it's exact relative to a model. You need to find the exact sampling distribution of the test statistic, as opposed to approximating it with the CLT as isalmost always done. 

Uncertainty about whether the poisson is a good model of traffic accidents or any other model assumption (your concern) is never captured in a p value.

Comment: @CloseToC That looks like a pretty good answer. You might consider posting it as an answer (possibly expanding it a little if you can). I believe I would upvote it as it stands.

Comment: @CloseToC: well, I agree with you if the question would have been posed in that way (for instance: compute an exact p-value given that .... are poisson distributed).